# Set timeout for Akka 2 typed actor

Tags: akka

How do I change the timeout from the default of 5 seconds for an Akka 2 typed actor?

The `TypedProps` constructor which mentions `timeout` is `protected[TypedProps]` (I don't know what that means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypedProps[Foo]().withTimeout(timeout)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the default timeout for typed actors you can set the `akka.actor.typed.timeout` value in your Akka config. For example:

```
akka.actor.typed.timeout=60s
```

According to the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#akka-actor) this is the "*Default timeout for typed actor methods with non-void return type*".

If you only want to change the timeout for a single typed actor, Robin Green's answer does the job.